# Windows 8 Upgrade to different language using registry

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry, language

I have a Windows 8 Enterprise Demo in German right now and already set up everything over 3 months. Now I bought the Windows 8 Pro version in English and followed the steps on this page so I can keep my programs and settings: 
http://www.windows-8-futter.de/enterprise/downgrade.html It fakes a Windows 8 Pro version instead of the Enterprise version using the registry to change the EditionID and the ProuctName.

When I get to the point where I am about to install it it tells me I can't upgrade from a German version to a English version because of the different languages. Is it possible to fake a English system language using the registry? And where do I find the right entry for it?

Comment: No;  What you want is not possible.

Comment: Then why is it possible to fake the Windows Version but not the system language?

Comment: The only thing you could try is to install the English language pack and remove the German language pack and see if that will work.  Windows upgrades are limited to the same language, this even applies, to the 8.1 update. Try [that](http://superuser.com/questions/618112/how-to-change-windows-8-core-installation-language-to-english)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AlpayY The installed language setting is stored in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language` registry key. The value is called `InstallLanguage`. It's a `REG_SZ` value which contains the language code (e.g. US English is `0409`). Here's a list of the supported values: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx